Trying to evaluate$ \int \sin^n(ax)\cos(x)dx $
I'm stuck trying to solve this integral
$$ \int \sin^n(ax)\cos(x)dx $$
I've tried u substitution
$$ u = \sin(ax) $$
$$ \frac{1}{a}\int u^n \cos(x) \frac{1}{\cos(ax)}du $$
but I'm stuck here since I don't know how to eliminate $ \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(ax)} $
I've also tried integration by parts but I don't know how to continue
$$ \sin^n(ax)\sin(x) - an\int \sin^{n-1}(ax)\cos(ax)\sin(x)dx $$
can someone help me?

next time please write \sin and \cos instead of sin and cos
